# On what story is Good Kill (2014) based?

Tags: good-kill

At the beginning of [***Good Kill***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3297330/) (2014) starring Ethan Hawke it is told it's based on actual events.

What is the definition of 'actual events' here? Does it stay for true/real story events? Because the Wiki page doesn't mention anything.

Is *Good Kill* a true story or not?

Comment: "Based on" is **highly** fluid.

Comment: Does the first paragraph looks like something you've seen? https://www.livescience.com/40959-military-drone-war-psychology.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Officially*, Egan's fictional character is based on a composite of stories from drone pilots. [Says the film's director](https://screenanarchy.com/2015/05/interview-good-kill-director-andrew-niccol-discusses-the-view-from-above.html):

> When it says based on true events, **what that means is that even though the pilot that Ethan Hawke plays is a composite character, every strike that you see has occurred.** I did not make any of that. Nothing that you see happening was embellished. I spoke to drone pilots, in particular the case of the woman who he tries to rescue, they say seeing atrocities like that had nothing to do with their mission, and they cannot act to expose themselves, so they don't. But they have seen these atrocities and they would definitely like to act.

*Unofficially*, it might be based on the story of Brandon Bryant, though it's a touchy subject. [Bryant critiqued an early version of the script](https://www.newsweek.com/2015/05/22/watch-drone-331949.html) and suggests the producers [might've used his notes and later snubbed him](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/gvyeg4/can-good-kill-make-the-public-care-about-the-drone-war):

> I was thinking specifically of Brandon Bryant, the former Air Force drone operator who has become a de facto spokesperson for an invisible air force suffering from deep remorse over their kills, the bad ones and the good ones. A 2013 DoD study reported that drone operators can suffer from the same combat stress as aircraft pilots, including PTSD. **Bryant says he was approached by the producers of *Good Kill* in 2013 and gave notes on an early script, but says they mostly dropped communications with him.**
>
> **"Andrew Niccol took my story and warped it to his own," says Bryant**, who has seen the film. "They snubbed me and created a terrible film with no intelligence behind it."

In fact, [The Telegraph goes as far as saying](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/film/film-news/11525499/good-kill-drone-pilot-true-story.html) the film was 'loosely based' on Bryant's experiences.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I highly doubt that last strike occurred in reality. He dropped bombs on multiple civilians including women but was angry that one of them was getting abused so he drops one because it's personal?

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4417/49).